# Best way to modify items in ObservableCollection with a form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that collects data in the background, displays data with one window, and has another form that can be used to update data objects. Data is stored in an observable collection that can be accessed application wide.

I would like to know the best way to edit the data with one form (the form must have an option to save the data, or cancel editing), and have the other window still display current data.

My idea right now is to have the form bind to a copy of the data object being edited, and then only replace the object in the ObservableCollection when the user confirms the changes. But I would like to know if there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Thanks Fabien, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would have the object expose both inprogess and final values.  Bind to the final and have a method in the object to copy inprogress to final.